# Count Projects in a Scratch Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scratch

I recently wrote a small Python 3 script to count the number of projects in a Scratch studio:

```python3
import re, functools
import requests

PARSE_RE = re.compile(r"""^
                          (?:  http://  |  https://  |  //  )?   # optional header
                          scratch\.mit\.edu/studios/             # main part of URL
                          (\d+)                                  # studio ID
                          (?:  /projects  )?                     # optional /projects
                          /?                                     # optional trailing slash
                          $
                            |
                          ^(\d+)$                                # alternative: just a number for the studio ID
                          """, re.VERBOSE)

EXIT_NO_ARGS = 1
EXIT_INVALID_STUDIO_ID = 2

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=16)
def query_page(studio_id, page, verbose):
    if verbose:
        print(end="Querying page {0}... ".format(page))
    url = "https://scratch.mit.edu/site-api/projects/in/{0}/{1}/".format(studio_id, page)
    text = requests.get(url).text
    if verbose:
        print("done")
    return text

def is_404(page_html):
    # The 404 page is a full webpage with a <!DOCTYPE>
    return ("<!D" in page_html)

def count_li(page_html):
    # Counts the number of instances of the string "<li" in the argument
    return page_html.count("<li")

def count_pages(studio_id, verbose=False):
    page_maximum = 1
    while True:
        page_html = query_page(studio_id, page_maximum, verbose)
        if is_404(page_html):
            page_minimum = page_maximum // 2
            break
        page_maximum *= 2

    # preform a binary search to find the first 404 studio
    while page_maximum - page_minimum > 1:
        page_num = (page_minimum + page_maximum) // 2
        page_html = query_page(studio_id, page_num, verbose)
        if is_404(page_html):
            page_maximum = page_num
        else:
            page_minimum = page_num

    page_count = page_minimum
    highest_page_html = query_page(studio_id, page_count, verbose)
    highest_page_project_count = count_li(highest_page_html)
    total = (page_count - 1) * 60 + highest_page_project_count
    return total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Usage:")
        print("  {0} <url or studio ID>:    counts the projects in that studio".format(sys.argv[0]))
        print("  {0} -v <url or studio ID>: verbose mode (logs all queries)".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(EXIT_NO_ARGS)

    verbose = ("-v" in sys.argv)
    studio_match = PARSE_RE.match(sys.argv[-1])
    if not studio_match:
        print("Error: Invalid studio ID")
        print("Must be a URL (scratch.mit.edu/studios/12345678) or a number (12345678)")
        sys.exit(EXIT_INVALID_STUDIO_ID)
    studio_id = studio_match.group(1) or studio_match.group(2)
    print(count_pages(studio_id, verbose))
```

It requires `requests`. It can be called from the command line as `python3 count.py https://scratch.mit.edu/studios/???` (where `???` is the studio ID), or it can be imported as a module and called using `count.count_pages`. It also supports a verbose logging mode which logs all requests.

How could this be improved?

Answer (score 1):

I would highlight the following areas of possible improvements:

- **argument parsing**: even though you have only 2 arguments to handle, using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) would simplify the code and improve readability. It would also might make sense to have "url or studio ID" defined in a custom type, raising `ArgumentTypeError` if validation fails
- **HTML parsing**: in general, parsing HTML with regexes or using `str.count()`, `str.find()` is [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Consider switching to an HTML parser like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` instead
- **HTTP requests**: instead of using `requests.get()` every single time, initialize [`session = requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and re-use it using `session.get()`. This would make a positive and noticable impact on performance.

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase

  And, see if you can improve on detecting `404` - would issuing `.head()` requests instead of `.get()` and checking `.status_code` work instead of downloading the whole page and checking for `<!D` in the HTML code.